# Why is ansi_nulls on in a new session when it is turned OFF at the database level?

Tags: t-sql, null, sql-server-2008-r2

In the database options, the ANSI NULLS Enabled option is set to false. I can further confirm this by running:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('mydb', 'IsAnsiNullsEnabled')
```

which gives me 0.

Interestingly, whenever I open a new query window from the same database and run this:

```
IF (NULL = NULL)
BEGIN
print 'true'
END
ELSE
begin
PRINT 'false'
END
```

it gives me 'false' every time. It only gives me 'true' if I manually turn ansi_nulls off by running:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Management Studio (SSMS), then you may have it set in your default query options.

To check this, click "Tools..Options" to open the Option dialog.   Then navigate to "Query Execution > SQL Server > ANSI".

The database setting is a default and is only used if there is no session, query or connection setting specified.

Comment: Thanks Barry! That was it!